# Locally store the Data when the internet not connected to device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When the app was not to connect to internet value of the store locally after internet connect value will pass to the database in ionic 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use Several Approaches for this.

1). LocalStorage   // localStorage.setItem()

2). Secure LocalStorage  //   [Check This Storage Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage)

3). SQLlite // [Check This SQLite plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite)

Use Network Plugin ([Network Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/network)) to detect connection state and save your values in storage you are using.